# PHP : searching text/word in line range file txt

Tags: php, file, search, range, line

i want to find a word in line range from a text file using php. Here's the text file:

```
1 asdcasdc
2 asdcadsc
3 asdc found asdcac
4 ascdsc found asd
5 kjhblk
6 kjn
7 found asdcac
8 asdcasd found
9 asdcasdc
10 asdc
11 asdc
```

i want to searching 'found' in range 5-11 of the line from the text file. How would I get the output like this :

```
7 found asdcac
8 asdcasd found
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated

-php noobie

Comment: Maybe regex like `(^(?:[5-9]|[1-9][0-9]+).*found.*)`...

Answer (score 0):

Something like this would do the trick

```
$content = file(__DIR__ . '/yourfile.txt');

// Grab the lines you want to search between
// This will search lines 5-11
$lines = array_slice($content, 5, 6, true);
$found = array_filter($lines, function($line) { return strpos($line, 'found') !== false; });
print_r($found);
```

Just change the file_get_contents to your actual file.

Also for some references here's [array_slice](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-slice.php) and [array_filter](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-filter.php)